# Quill is not working with vuejs and showing arrow image

Tags: vue.js, quill

I've followed the [quill playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/#autogrow-height) guide but using vuejs and it doesn't work. There's no error on the browser but a weird arrow is showing.

[image]

Example: https://codepen.io/danny1014/pen/gOLZNZQ

```
var quill = new Quill("#quill-container", {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
      ["image", "code-block"]
    ]
  },
  scrollingContainer: "#scrolling-container",
  placeholder: "Compose an epic...",
  theme: "bubble"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you import css file of theme "bubble"?
Something like **@import "~quill/dist/quill.snow.css";**

Answer (score 0):

Try using snow theme instead of bubble